# Postgres database "name" does not exist, but it does

Tags: postgresql, psql

My Postgres cluster has 4 databases. I see them all from pgAdmin 3.

But when I try to connect to these databases from another machine, I have an error: database `dbname` does not exist.

I can connect only to the database named `postgres`.

What's wrong with my other databases?

Why do I have this error? The databases exist, I swear.

Comment: does your user have access to your postgres db? if your doesn't doesn't have access to db then grant your current user access and try again.

Comment: Connect to database `postgres` and run: `SELECT datname, datallowconn, datacl FROM pg_database;` Append the output to your question. Also, describe with what software and exactly how you try to connect from the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have access to the database , you can use following to change the ownership of db to the required user:

`alter database the_db  owner to username;`

Comment: Owner is always user postgres for all databases. And I try to connect with this user from another machine.